# Select single cell JTable with mouse (eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, swing, jtable, mouse, cell

I would like to know how I can select a single cell from a JTable with the mouse and after keep the value of the cell in a variable. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MouseListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more information and examples.

When you click on a cell you will need to get the mouse point from the `MouseEvent` and convert that to a cell in the table. Then you can get the data from the table. The basic code would be:

```
int row = table.rowAtPoint(...);
int column = table.columnAtPoint(...);
Object cellValue = table.getValueAt(row, column);
```